# Replicate poor wi-fi for testing

Tags: testing, networking, wifi, bandwidth

I want to test an iPad app that needs an internet connection.  I want to sit at my desk next to my router and test it against a poor wifi connection.  How can I replicate a really poor wifi connection?  Wrap the router in tin foil?  Try and limit the router connection speed to the internet?

Thanks.

Comment: You could put other devices into the wifi network and for example download large <b>different</b> files (or streaming video), something that will also increase the requests to your router

Comment: What specifically do you mean by 'really poor'?  Is it just a high packet loss rate through the wifi?  Does this test require lower signal strength, or simply lower throughput / higher packet loss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I tested the app using the iOS simulator in Xcode on a Mac, then used the excellent Network Link Conditioner tool (that comes with Xcode) to tune my network speed as required.  Worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Better ways to do these tests are to use RF isolation chambers.

Did you try reducing the power levels on Access Point to minimum?

On a different note, if you want to have a bad Wi-Fi environment,create lot of interference on same channel from another Access Point.